# Place Order in Checkout takes long time

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento store.
During Place Order it takes long time to save order(Approx 2 mins).

I followed the below links. But that didn't helped me.

[link1](http://www.alphaquad.co.uk/blog/2013/01/is-your-magento-checkout-slow)

[link2](http://www.devproblems.com/magento-place-order-slow-fixed/)

Somebody help me.

Comment: Still in beta, but you may want to check out http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed on your store?  In particular a module that observes any of the order save methods?

Comment: @PixieMedia : No custom modules installed. I have analysed the code. Time takes when the function sendNewOrderEmail is called on the object $order.